# Explanation of structures program

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, structure

I came across this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct gospel
{
    int num;
    char mess1[50];
    char mess2[50];
} m1 = { 2, "If you are driven by success",
"make sure that it is a quality drive"
};

int main()
{
        struct gospel m2, m3;
        m2 = m1;
        m3 = m2;
        printf("\n%d %s %s", m1.num, m2.mess1, m3.mess2);

    return 0;
}
```

However I couldn't get what the line m1 =

```
{ 2, "If you are driven by success",
"make sure that it is a quality drive"
};
```

means? Can someone please explain its meaning and also the output of this program with justification.

Comment: So what *is* the output of the program?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The output is 2 If you are driven by success make sure that it is a quality drive

Comment: so *which parts* exactly are you having problems with? Have you tried changing something in the program and compiling and running it again?

Comment: I couldn't get what the line { 2, "If you are driven by success",
"make sure that it is a quality drive"
}; means

Comment: that is am I assigning values to m1.num, m1.mess1, m1.mess2 through this?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Please see my above comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct gospel
{
    int num;
    char mess1[50];
    char mess2[50];
} m1 = { 2, "If you are driven by success",
"make sure that it is a quality drive" };
```

Is defining a global variable that is of type `struct gospel`

It is the same as writing

```
struct gospel
{
    int num;
    char mess1[50];
    char mess2[50];
};

struct gospel m1 = { 2, "If you are driven by success",
"make sure that it is a quality drive" };
```

The curly brackets assign the values of the struct to the variable by order - so m1.num is assigned the value 2, m1.mess1 is assigned the value "If you are driven by success" and m1.mess2 is assigned the value "make sure that it is a quality drive"

Would recommend reading [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) if you want to learn more about this type of initialization.